# Ionic native file plugin: file.readAsArrayBuffer() => Uncaught RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I doing a intership project in Ionic. In this project, I have to read mbtiles files (via the `@ionic-native/file` plugin) and put them in leaflet (via the `leaflet-tilelayer-mbtiles-ts`plugin for leaflet). i do it like this:

```
this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(PATH, MBITILEFILENAME).then(res =>{
                L.tileLayer.mbTiles(res,{
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    attribution: "mbtiles"
                }).addTo(this.map)
            })
```

As I don't use the Ionic test app for some reasons, I have to test my app directly on the phone, and use Android studio console to see what's going on.

**Here's the problem:**
When I use a little mbtiles file (10Mo, testing file) it work, but when I use a bigger file (880Mo, file it has to read in prod environment) Android Console read me this:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(312)] "Uncaught RangeError: Array buffer
>   allocation failed", source: http://localhost/cordova.js (312)

I tried to search for the `file.readAsArrayBuffer()` size limit, but I found nothing.

Can you tell me what is the`file.readAsArrayBuffer()` size limit? Any solution to bypass this limit with Ionic? Or something that can solve my problem?

Comment: Is this simply the phone not having enough memory to hold the bigger file in memory twice. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/5e12b5e9f63b12aef5198e9a72ac8d7b8e834442/src/android/FileUtils.java#L1089 (One copy for the byte [] and another for the conversion to a ByteArray)

Comment: @GarrettBarlocker that was what I understand, but do you know how can I do to load only the needed part of the mbtiles in the memory?

Comment: I think using a 880MB file in client side is realy a bad idea. Use simple tiles instead of mbTiles.

Comment: @Gilsdav If I could I would, by the way. But the compagny want (absurdly) absolutly that and their is no way to change their mind (and I tried a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it, and forgot to post the answer. I used WebView from "@ionic-native/ionic-webview" so the map is do not need to be fully loaded, just the part needed.

```
var pathToFile =
    this.file.externalDataDirectory + PATHTOFILE
var truePath = WebView.convertFileSrc(pathToFile);
L.tileLayer(truePath + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: "local"
}).addTo(this.map);
```